# Transparent background in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-visio-2013

I'm using Visio 2013 and I'm not able so save my drawings with a transparent background (background always ends up with white color)

The sheet background is "no background".

[image]

When I click "save as .PNG" (or .gif) there opens up a options menue. There I can also choose a background color but there are just colors and no "transparent" options.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your PNG options simply tick Transparancy Color:

[image: PNG Options]

Don't amend the colour, leave both as they are, and save.

In this example Drawing1 was saved with this option ticked, and Drawing 2 without:

[image: Proof]

Comment: Thank you very much!! It makes me feel stupid :-[ I thought with this box you simply can give the transparency any color. Not actually make it transparent. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, it's really not clear to be honest with you :)

Comment: Can i do this programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

To preserve partially transparent content:

1. Export as a .SVG file
2. (optional) In the the exported file, increase the "width" and "height" attributes. This will increase the render resolution in step 4
3. Open the .SVG in internet explorer. Microsoft's extensions [break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) SVG in other apps.
4. Right click the displayed image and save it as a .png